# How do I delete or hide objects?

Tags: qml

I'm trying to hide or delete an item (a button)

Here is the code:

```
//when you click on the button I try to delete the   button2
Button {
    id: button2 
    text: qsTr("DRINA")

    ToolTip.visible: hovered
    ToolTip.text: qsTr("Save the active project")
}
Button {
    id: button3
    text: qsTr("delete")

    ToolTip.visible: hovered
    ToolTip.text: qsTr("delete the active project")
    clicked: button2. //alas but it does not offer options like delete and hide
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*I also want to hide or delete an element of the ColumnLayout type (I hope this is done the same way as with the Button element)*

Comment: Just set the button's `visible` property to `false`.

Comment: @JarMan thanks. how to delete on click ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiding a button is done by setting the `visible` property to `false`. You're also using the `clicked` signal incorrectly. You shouldn't assign anything to the signal itself. Instead you define the `onClicked` handler for the signal. So your code should look like this:

```
Button {
    id: button3
    text: qsTr("delete")

    ToolTip.visible: hovered
    ToolTip.text: qsTr("delete the active project")
    onClicked: button2.visible = false
}
```

You can't delete a QML item that has been defined statically the way you are showing. You can only hide it. If you change the code to create the `Button` dynamically (for example, with a `Loader`), then it can be deleted.

```
Component {
    id: dynamicBtn
    Button {
        // Button that can be deleted
    }
}

Loader {
    id: btnLoader
    sourceComponent: dynamicBtn
}

Button {
    // Unload (delete) the other button
    onClicked: btnLoader.sourceComponent = undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind the action to the `clicked` signal. What you should do is set the `visible` property of the button you want to delete to `false` in the handler of that signal, which is `onClicked`

The code should look like this:
`onClicked: { button2.visible = false; }`